# When run sp_addlinkedserver show message:No server found in sys.servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

> Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Procedure TRIGGER_INSERT, Line 31
>   Can not find server '***' in sys.servers. Please verify that the specified server name is correct. If needed, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

I get this above error message, but I do not understand the reasons for the implementation of sp_addlinkedserver error. What should I do to solve the problem?

Here's my code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIGGER_INSERT]
ON [dbo].[TABLE]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Create a server connection
    EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
        @server = 'SERVER',
        @srvproduct = '',
        @provider = 'SQLOLEDB',
        @datasrc = '0.0.0.0'

    -- Create a user login connection
    EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
        @rmtsrvname = 'SERVER',
        @useself = 'false',
        @locallogin = NULL,
        @rmtuser = '**',
        @rmtpassword = '**'

    -- Delete the user login connection
    EXEC sp_droplinkedsrvlogin
        @rmtsrvname = 'SERVER',
        @locallogin = NULL

    -- Delete the server connection
    EXEC sp_dropserver
        @server = 'SERVER',
        @droplogins = NULL
END
GO
```

Comment: This is strange, but not because you've got "Can not find server '***' in sys.servers", but because you should get another error: **The procedure 'sys.sp_addlinkedserver' cannot be executed within a transaction**.For all 4 procedures: sp_addlinkedserver, sp_addlinkedsrvlogin, sp_droplinkedsrvlogin, sp_dropserver. Because the trigger is always a part of a transaction. So you just cannot put your code into a trigger

Comment: Thanks. I put these code out of trigger, and everything got right.